# Unusually high bandwith starting every day at exactly 4am

Tags: bandwidth, digital-ocean, high-load

Every day between exactly 4am and roughly 11-12am we're having this massive increase in bandwith which is causing a very high load on our server. I'm not able to pinpoint the exact cause and I was curious if you can point me in the right direction with how to identify the cause of this problem.

[image: digital_ocean_droplet_bandwith_graph_screenshot]

Comment: Check cronjobs, log entries around the time. If you can't find anything, log connections at intervals and check them for remote addresses that stand out.

Answer (score 0):

You could also create a cronjob that you log all outgoing traffic with iptables to a log file which you can review.

Comment: flow-tools (or other netflow implementation) looks much more appropriate for this problem

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the typical symptom for an automated backup. If you have scheduled backups configured, these will at least create a high I/O load and - if they use compression - also create a high cpu load.

Answer (score 0):

You're providing not near enough information for anyone to guess the actual reason for that traffic.

The general steps for analysis are:

- Check server and firewall logs for traffic patterns (common source addresses, repeating URLs) and error messages.
- Run network monitoring like netflow or sflow.